# Why is my filtering logic not working as expected for predictive search?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a tool that pulls property values from a .json file and estimates the impact of a potential tax override in my area based on people's property values. They should be able to search their property by street address, parcel ID#, or the owner's name. As they type, the app suggests potential matches dynamically.

I'm having an issue with the filtering logic for the name field. The data is stored inconsistantly, for example, some records are in as "LEV SAMUEL T", (last-first-middle) others are in simply as "SAMUEL LEV", (first-last). I need people to be able to find their property no matter what order they enter their name in, so I used the .split(" ") to break criteria when there is a space.

It's working, however, I am not getting results until an entire name is entered.

For example: record is "NARKEWICZ DAVID". If I search "NARKEWICZ", the records show up. however, if I search "NARK" (without completeing the entire name), nothing shows. I'd like the records to show even if it is just a partial match.

The other fields don't have this issue, for example "FLORENCE ROAD" will show records even if I just enter "FLORE".

Here's the entire app.js code:

```
"use strict";

const e = React.createElement;

//Create CSS styles as JS objects
const containerStyles = {
  width: "100%",
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "column",
  justifyContent: "flex-start",
  alignItems: "stretch"
};

const headerStyles = {
  width: "100%",
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "column",
  justifyContent: "flex-start",
  alignItems: "center",
  alignSelf: "center"
};

const headerTextStyles = {
  margin: 0
};

const inputStyles = {
  width: "50%",
  borderRadius: "3px",
  padding: "20px",
  height: "15px",
  alignSelf: "center"
};

const dataContainerStyles = {
  width: "100%",
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "column",
  justifyContent: "flex-start",
  alignItems: "center",
  marginTop: "20px"
};

const listContainer = {
  position: "relative",
  zIndex: 99
};

const listStyles = {
  width: "100%",
  overflow: "hidden",
  position: "absolute",
  top: 0,
  transform: "translateX(-50%)",
  left: "50%",
  alignSelf: "center",
  boxShadow: "0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",
  maxHeight: "400px",
  zIndex: 99,
  backgroundColor: "#fff"
};

const listItemStyles = {
  textAlign: "center",
  color: "white",
  fontWeight: "600",
  padding: "10px"
};

const rowStyles = {
  width: "40%",
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "row",
  justifyContent: "space-between",
  alignItems: "center",
  alignSelf: "center"
};
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedAddress: null,
      items: [],
      searchVal: "",
      data: []
    };

    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
    this.selectItem = this.selectItem.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("./values.json")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log("data", data);
        this.setState({ data });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  selectItem(item) {
    this.setState({
      selectedAddress: item,
      items: [],
      searchVal: ""
    });
  }

  highlightString(q, string) {
    return String(string).replace(
      q.toUpperCase(),
      `<span style="font-weight: bold;">${q.toUpperCase()}</span>`
    );
  }

  handleSearch(search) {
    this.setState({ searchVal: search });
    this.filterData(search);
  }

  filterData = debounce(search => {
    let items = [];
    if (search) {
      const q = search.toLowerCase();

      const ownerNameFilter = item => {
        const ownerName1 = item.OWNER1.toLowerCase().split(" ");
        const ownerName2 = item.OWNER2.toLowerCase().split(" ");
        const fullName = 
              item.OWNER1.toLowerCase() + " " + item.OWNER2.toLowerCase();
        //return [ownerName1, ownerName2];
        const fullNameDelim =fullName.toLowerCase().split(" ");
        return [fullNameDelim];

      };

      const addressFilter = item => {
        const addressNum = item.ADDR_NUM.toLowerCase();
        const fullAddress =
          item.ADDR_NUM.toLowerCase() + " " + item.FULL_STR.toLowerCase();
        const streetName = item.FULL_STR.toLowerCase();

        const fullAddressFiltered = fullAddress.toLowerCase().split(" ");

        let abbreviations = "";

        if (fullAddressFiltered.includes("rd")) {
          const abbreviationIndex = fullAddressFiltered.indexOf("rd");

          fullAddressFiltered[abbreviationIndex] = "road";
          abbreviations = fullAddressFiltered.join(" ");
        }

        if (fullAddressFiltered.includes("st")) {
          const abbreviationIndex = fullAddressFiltered.indexOf("st");

          fullAddressFiltered[abbreviationIndex] = "street";
          abbreviations = fullAddressFiltered.join(" ");
        }

        if (fullAddressFiltered.includes("ave")) {
          const abbreviationIndex = fullAddressFiltered.indexOf("ave");

          fullAddressFiltered[abbreviationIndex] = "avenue";
          abbreviations = fullAddressFiltered.join(" ");
        }

        return [streetName, addressNum, fullAddress, abbreviations];
      };

      items = this.state.data.reduce((acc, item) => {
        const searchProps = [
          ...addressFilter(item),
          ...ownerNameFilter(item),

          String(item["PROP ID"]).toLowerCase()
        ];

        for (let prop of searchProps) {
          if (!Array.isArray(prop)) {
            if (prop.includes(q)) {
              let markup = `
                             <span class="autocompleteAddress">${this.highlightString(
                               q,
                               item.ADDR_NUM
                             )} ${this.highlightString(q, item.FULL_STR)}</span>
                             <span class="autocompleteOwner">${this.highlightString(
                               q,
                               item.OWNER1
                             )} ${this.highlightString(
                q,
                item.OWNER2
              )} <span style="display: block;">${this.highlightString(
                q,
                item["PROP ID"] || ""
              )}</span></span>
                        `;

              item.markup = markup;
              acc.push(item);
              break;
            }
          } else {
            const searchTerms = search.split(" ");

            let doesMatch = false;

            if (searchTerms.every(term => prop.includes(term))) {
              doesMatch = true;
            }

            if (doesMatch) {
              let markup = `
                             <span class="autocompleteAddress">${this.highlightString(
                               q,
                               item.ADDR_NUM
                             )} ${this.highlightString(q, item.FULL_STR)}</span>
                             <span class="autocompleteOwner">${this.highlightString(
                               q,
                               item.OWNER1
                             )} ${this.highlightString(
                q,
                item.OWNER2
              )} <span style="display: block;">${this.highlightString(
                q,
                item["PROP ID"] || ""
              )}</span></span>
                        `;

              item.markup = markup;
              acc.push(item);
              break;
            }
          }
        }

        return acc;
      }, []);
    }
    this.setState({
      items: items
    });
  }, 500);

  formatNumber(num) {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
      style: "currency",
      currency: "USD"
    }).format(num);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container" style={containerStyles}>
        <div id="title" style={headerStyles}>
          <img className="logo" src="logo.png" />
          <p style={headerTextStyles}> City of Northampton</p>
          <p style={headerTextStyles}>Tax Override Calculator</p>
        </div>

        <input
          value={this.state.searchVal}
          onChange={e => this.handleSearch(e.target.value)}
          style={inputStyles}
          placeholder="Enter an address or parcel ID..."
        />

        {this.state.items.length !== 0 && (
          <div style={listContainer}>
            <div style={listStyles}>
              {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
                <p
                  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.markup }}
                  className="autocomplete-hover"
                  key={item["PROP ID"] || index}
                  onClick={() => this.selectItem(item)}
                  style={listItemStyles}
                />
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}

        <div style={dataContainerStyles}>
          <div style={rowStyles}>
            <p className="label"> Parcel ID:</p>
            {this.state.selectedAddress ? (
              <p>{`${this.state.selectedAddress["PROP ID"]}`}</p>
            ) : (
              <p>None Selected</p>
            )}
          </div>

          <div style={rowStyles}>
            <p className="label"> Address:</p>
            {this.state.selectedAddress ? (
              <p>{`${this.state.selectedAddress["ADDR_NUM"]} ${
                this.state.selectedAddress["FULL_STR"]
              }`}</p>
            ) : (
              <p>None Selected</p>
            )}
          </div>

          <div style={rowStyles}>
            <p className="label">Owner:</p>
            {this.state.selectedAddress ? (
              <p>{`${this.state.selectedAddress["OWNER1"]} ${
                this.state.selectedAddress["OWNER2"]
              }`}</p>
            ) : (
              <p>None Selected</p>
            )}
          </div>

          <div style={rowStyles}>
            <p className="label">2020 Assessed Value:</p>
            {this.state.selectedAddress ? (
              <p>{`${this.formatNumber(
                parseFloat(this.state.selectedAddress["TOTAL VAL"])
              )}`}</p>
            ) : (
              <p>None Selected</p>
            )}
          </div>

          <div style={rowStyles}>
            <p className="label">Total Annual Impact:</p>
            {this.state.selectedAddress ? (
              <p>{`${this.formatNumber(
                (parseFloat(
                  this.state.selectedAddress["TOTAL VAL"].replace(/,/g, "")
                ) /
                  1000) *
                  0.67
              )}`}</p>
            ) : (
              <p>None Selected</p>
            )}
          </div>
            <div style={rowStyles}>
            <p className="label">Total Quarterly Impact:</p>
            {this.state.selectedAddress ? (
              <p>{`${this.formatNumber(
                (parseFloat(
                  this.state.selectedAddress["TOTAL VAL"].replace(/,/g, "")
                ) /
                  4000) *
                  0.67
              )}`}</p>
            ) : (
              <p>None Selected</p>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector("#root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, domContainer);
```

Comment: Adding your entire code including CSS is not really relevant here, can you add only the part of your logic that is not working, something like a [mcve] ?

Comment: By the way you should make a single file such big like that. Break the code is very essential skill. And it also seems that you are repeating much code.

Comment: This appears to be React code. If that's the case, you may want to add the `reactjs` tag so that experts in that framework see your question.